# How to call JSON data with var name

Tags: javascript, json

I'd like to get data from JSON with the use of vars.
I've got a object: `result`

```
object {jan: 240, feb: 821, mar: 1190, apr: 1046, maj: 892}
```

In that object I can call: `result.jan;`.
This will give me: 240

But instead of using hardcoded: `result.jan`, I'd like to use: `result.(variable)thisMonth;`

How can I do this?

Comment: Please use 
result[thisMonth] . Please look into https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects for more details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use `result[thisMonth]`

Comment: Thank you. How could i miss this! I must be tired! I will use this!

Comment: Your welcome. Also, i think answer of `shushanth p` looks better then mine, so you can vote for his answer

Answer (score 1):

you can use it with variable as below

```
  var obj = {jan: 240, feb: 821, mar: 1190, apr: 1046, maj: 892}
  var month = 'jan';

  var result = obj[month]; // 240
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also access properties by means of a bracket notation in JS. 
[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors](http://link)

```
var obj = {jan: 240, feb: 821, mar: 1190, apr: 1046, maj: 892}
var mon = "jan";
var result = obj[mon]; //prints 240
```

Answer (score 0):

Index the table value using keys:

`result[thisMonth]`

`thisMonth` must return a string literal refering a property in the table, such as `"jan"`.